# Particular website is not opening

Tags: web-services, web-applications, web, dns

Am having hostname in bigrock and webhosting in godaddy.I made changes in DNS servers in Bigrock and it is now pointing to Godaddy servers. It is not opening in my Work computer,but it is opening in my laptop and in my mobile.I tried to change the google DNS in my Work computer and i installed open DNS to my local machine,but it is not working.Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [propagation](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1746/what-factors-affect-dns-propagation-time). To empty your DNS resolver cache:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `cmd` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. Type `ipconfig /flushdns` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. Close the Command Prompt and open your site!